# Correct way to bind member functions?

Tags: c++, function, bind, member-functions

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

typedef std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> func_list;

class Thing {
private:
    func_list flist;
    void _sayHi() {
        cout << "hi" << endl;
    }
    void _sayNum(int num) {
        cout << num << endl;
    }
public:
    Thing();
    void sayHi();
    void sayNum(int num);
    void executeFunctions();
};

void Thing::sayHi() {
    flist.push_back(
        std::bind(&Thing::_sayHi, this)  //  Unsure of the correct usage here
    );
}

void Thing::sayNum(int num) {
    flist.push_back(
        std::bind(&Thing::_sayNum, this, num)  //  Unsure of the correct usage here
    );
}

void Thing::executeFunctions() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < flist.size(); i++) {
        flist.at(i)();
    }
}

int main() {
    Thing thing = Thing();
    thing.sayHi();
    thing.sayNum(5);

    thing.executeFunctions();
}
```

My goal is just to store functions when they are called so they can be executed at a later time. I can bind non-member functions using `std::bind(&functionName, param1, param2)` but inside a function this no longer works and using `std::bind(&Class::ClassMemberFunctionName, this)` leaves me with a `unresolved externals` error:

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Thing::Thing(void)" (??0Thing@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
>
> Error  2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

What is the correct way to bind this class functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing implementation of `Thing::Thing()` constructor.

Comment: Note that it looks like the solution here is to remove the declaration, not add a definition, since there's nothing in the class that needs explicit initialisation.